How to connect 3V dc motor to 5V power source?
I can't get a grasp of electro-engineering basics
Given a DC motor 3V and 5.12V power supply from a phone charger
I thought I can use voltage divider to divide 5.12V into 3V and 2.12V, seems logical
      R1 (2.12V)  R2 (3V)
         2k2       3k3
+5V ----^v^v^-----^v^v^----- GND

Here is voltages I get
      R1 (5.12V)  R2 (0V)
         2k2       3k3
+5V ----^v^v^-----^v^v^----- GND
               |
               |---MOTOR---- +0V

But when I plug the motor in, the second part becomes parallel, motor resistance is almost 0 and the second part resulting resistance becomes r = (1/3300 + 1/0.1)^-1 = 0.1 Ohm so its resistance indistinguishable from resistance of a regular wire, so that doesn't drop voltage at all
For me the point is to use basic building blocks like resistors, diodes, etc to build an intuition of how to make circuits the right way, I came from the world of software development, can't get how this should be done at all

The current used by the motor is high enough to "short" the resistors used. You can use a DC-DC converter (buck with high enough current) to supply the motor and/or use a PWM system.

What do you consider by "high enough current"? F130 DC motor datasheet states that no load current is 120ma, I'm not sure what is meant under "no load". DC-DC converter looks an overkill to me, isn't there a way to do the same using basic elements? If voltage divider can't handle a motor so which devices it can handle, what's the point of it at all?

I'm trying to grasp the essence of electrical engineering. For me it now looks like guessing in terms of high-low enough current, voltages. I thought it was possible to completely evaluate the circuit and provide exact values of needed properties (voltage, amperage)

This Q&A explains why a voltage divider won't work here.

Does this answer your question? When would I use a voltage regulator vs a voltage divider?


For me the point is to use basic building blocks like resistors,
diodes, etc to build an intuition of how to make circuits the right
way...

You might consider substituting diodes here to reduce 5V to near 3V. When current flows through a diode, voltage across its terminals is much more constant compared to voltage dropped across a resistor:

voltage drop across a resistor scales with current through it
voltage drop across a diode approaches a fixed voltage (approx 0.7V) nearly independent of current

Diodes break when too much current flows, so you'll need big ones that can take current of a stalled motor, hopefully without overheating.
Diodes still have some internal resistance, so motor voltage will drop somewhat when it works hard.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This solution might be acceptable for a small motor. 1N4001 diodes can manage currents up to about one amp - you may need a larger diode that can handle more current. If the combined internal resistance of three diodes is still too much, try using two.

I think this solution is not generic. With resistors I could calculate exact voltages by selecting specific resistances (at the cost of not being able to use it as I intended), with diodes on the other hand it's not possible to make 3.3V (for example), either 2.9 or 3.6 from 5V supply

True, not a generic solution, but a far better one than series resistor for a motor load. For most motor applications, series resistance should be reduces to a minimum. In fact, a negative resistance can make motors behave better. But negative resistance is complex, requiring active transistor circuits - beyond simple resistors, diodes as specified.
